# Adjective for "Visual Cacophony"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective that describes something very visually crowded or busy?  *Cacophonous* is perfect, but it describes sound.

Comment: Jackson Pollock ;)

Comment: 'busy' is the first thing that came to my mind from your title question. Are you looking for something coined from Ancient Greek?

Comment: @Rea, yes, I've heard it used that way. I was just checking to see if it had already been given as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your specific situation, I think *chaos*, *confusion*, *turmoil*, and *tumult* all have the chance to do nicely.  However, I also like the potential for metaphor here; if you can use it in this context, why not just use *cacophony* or *visual cacophony*?  We even use *loud* in English to describe brightly colored things; sound can be used to express a visual experience so intense that it seems to bleed into the other senses.

Comment: "Tumult" is a good word.  I've never heard it before!

Comment: Agreed.  Aural descriptives have been commonly used to describe visual effects for as long as we have a written record.  I see nothing wrong with the metaphor as it stands.   "Tumult", in fact, is fundamentally an aural descriptive;  the other words work just as well.

Comment: I was considering using "visual cacophony" and this answer assures me I'm not alone. @KylePearson I'm reminded of the onomatopoetic "bling!" that is used for diamonds or sharp swords.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps one could describe the thing as ["cluttered":](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cluttered)

> 1.Scattered with a disorderly mixture of objects; littered

For example, "The table top was cluttered with an endless amount of items"

There also the other examples of *croweded*, *messy*, *littered*, *dishevel*, *scrambled*(like scrambled egg), and my personal favourite, **topsy-turvy**

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

> **motley** *n. pl.* **motleys**:
>
> 1. The parti-colored attire of a court jester.
> 2. A heterogeneous, often incongruous mixture of elements.

(Definition courtesy of *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition*)

Answer (score 3):

*Garish* is the closest I can think of.

*Cacography* describes bad handwriting or scribbling.  You could help reenforce *cacovisual* as a new word.  It was coined elsewhere but only has two English references on the web according to Google.

You might describe it as *assaulting* (one's senses), or *a visual train-wreck*.

Some related words and phrases are *groteque* and *eye sore*.

Answer (score 2):

Yiddish has the wonderful word [ungapatchka](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ungapatchka), which means overdone, garish, distastefully ornate, or over-the-top; I think it's exactly what you're looking for. Too bad it doesn't have the currency in English that some other Yiddish words do.

"Garish" is not a bad English word for this, come to think of it!

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a single word, but your own "visual cacophony" hits the nail squarely on the head. I can visualise that dischordant mess immediately!

Answer (score 2):

Down south, we say "gaudy", and although this tends to be a term of disparagement used against presumptuous decor and attire it is often extended to other situations, as well.

"The colors they used in that mall architecture were just gaudy;  i can't look at the place for longer than two minutes, and it give me a headache."

Answer (score 1):

Cornucopia may suit if it's a positive abundance of things. Although not what you are looking for I expect!

Cornucopia is a noun though (as is cacophony)

Comment: This word does not seem to fit the bill. The definition I have is "an abundant, overflowing supply."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the noun form of **spattering**, which means to have many distinct elements spread chaotically over a surface, e.g. a spattering of paint on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the word *tumult* — that describes noise as well!

A "visual tumult" doesn't sound as good as a "visual cacophony". Depending on the situation, we could use a number of terms. I'd go with "a riot of (something)", be it colour or whatever the visual focus is that is so cacophonous.

Answer (score 0):

David Brin appears to have coined the word cacophote in his book Sundiver, to refer to a visual cacophony.

See [this excerpt from the book.](http://lichen.phys.uregina.ca/eclectic/sundiver.html) I instantly understood the meaning upon reading it, but the word does not appear in the OED, and a google search turns up only this passage.

Comment: Hi, could you add some links or references to this answer please? Answers here are generally expected to have some sort of backup.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I tried editing, but it has been placed on peer review. I answered this question before creating an account, which may be causing some issue.

Comment: @Randal'Thor In any event, a google search will turn up cacophote in Brin's book, but it is not in the OED.

Comment: @JimConant Yep, it looks like you now have two separate accounts, which is why you needed peer review to edit your own posts. Please see the instructions [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge your accounts; this will enable you to edit your own posts freely and comment on any post. (In the meantime, I've voted to approve your pending edit.)

Comment: Ah the mysterious downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would see this word in the reviews of black metal bands: Carnivalesque.

Also: maddening, phantasmagoric (if you want to bend them).

Comment: Please could you [edit] this answer to include some citations, e.g. links to dictionary definitions of these words? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is the adjective ***cacoptic***, a neologism proposed in:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/5790/cacopsis)
>
> Cacoptis:
>
> cacopsis means "eye offending".(noun)
> and its adjective form is cacoptic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you mean *cacoptic*?